# Regularity of Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-differential-equations, regularity

Consider solutions $\rho_{1,2}$ of the Fokker-Planck equation

$$\begin{cases}\partial_t \rho_i = \Delta \rho_i + \nabla \cdot (\rho_i \nabla \Phi_{1,2})\\
\rho_i(0,\cdot) = \rho^0 \end{cases}$$

for two potentials $\Phi_{1,2}\colon [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ and some (smooth if necessary) initial condition $\rho^0$. I am aware that sufficient regularity of $\Phi_{1,2}$ guarantees that the solutions exist in the classical sense as smooth functions $\rho_{1,2} \in C^\infty((0,T)\times \mathbb{R}^d)$, and my question is the following:

Are there results that bound $\left\| \rho_1(t) - \rho_2(t)\right\|$ for $t\in (0,T)$ in terms of $\sup_{s\in [0,T]}\left\|\Phi_1(s)-\Phi_2(s)\right\|$ for some norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ (like a Sobolev norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)}$), under some assumptions on $\Phi_{1,2}$ and $\rho^0$?

I'd be interested also in the case where the norms concerning $\rho$ and $\Phi$ are different, but it should be on a functional level (bounding the Wasserstein distance between $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ doesn't help in my case, for example). If the dimension plays a role, then $d \in \left\{1,2\right\}$.

Comment: Since the steady states are $\exp(-\Phi_i)$ and since the solution is expected to locally "look like" the steady state straight away, you cannot expect to get a bound on $\rho_1 - \rho_2$ in a norm that enforces higher regularity than the one you enforce on the $\Phi$'s. If you're thinking about weights at infinity rather than regularity, then you would expect to get bounds in a norm that enforces fast decay at infinity using only uniform control on the $\Phi$'s (and enough derivatives).

Comment: Assuming  you know that  $\rho$ solving $$\partial_{t}\rho  =\Delta\rho+\text{div}\left(\rho\nabla\phi+F\right) \text{ with } \rho\left(t=0\right)=\rho_{0},$$ verifies
$$
\| \rho(t) \|_1 \leq C(\| \phi\|_3) \left( \| F\|_2+\| \rho_0\|_4\right)
$$
Then you have by linearity
$$
\| \rho_1(t)-\rho_2(t) \|_1 \leq C\left( \left\|\frac{\phi_1+\phi_2}{2} \right\|_3 \right) \left( \left\|\frac{ \rho_{1}+\rho_{2}}{2} \nabla(\phi_{1}-\phi_{2})\right\|_2+\| \rho_{0,1} -\rho_{0,2}\|_4\right).
$$